# Check in bash if make has done something

Tags: bash, make, gnu-make

I'm calling `make` from a bash script. Part of the rest of the script only needs to  be executed if `make` actually did something (i.e. it doesn't say `nothing to be done for...`).

How would I check on that in bash? The return code is the same as when something *does* happen (and doesn't fail), so I can't use that. Is there a better way than comparing `make`'s output and see if it contains `nothing to be done for`?

I'm using GNU Make 4.0.

Comment: Are you sure the return code is the same? It should be 0 if the make is unsuccessful, 2 if there are no rules to generate the target ... you've tried to run `echo $?` after the make that ends with `nothing to be done for?`

Comment: @LilloX yes, I have tried `echo $?`. Both `nothing to be done for` and an actual make are successful, so they return 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your workflow can accomodate it, you can send `make` on a trial run before you run it to update files:

> **-q, --question**
>
> ‘‘Question  mode’’.   Do  not run any commands, or print anything;
>          just return an exit status that is zero if the  specified  targets
>          are already up to date, nonzero otherwise.

(I am somewhat surprised this is not part of `--recon`'s behaviour.)

Comment: `make` does not implement `--dry-run` did you mean `-n`?

Comment: @schily: you're right, I just always think it should be `--dry-run` where it's `--recon`.

Comment: The options you mention are part of `gmake` but not supported by `make`.

Comment: @schily Please stop trolling. The question explicitly states that the make implementation is GNU make.

Comment: If people write `gmake` when they are talking about `gmake`, nobody needs to correct them. So please stop trolling.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do what you want. Tested with GNU grep.

```
mk_output=$(make)   # add whatever make options you use
if printf '%s\n' "$mk_output" | grep -qF 'Nothing to be done for'
then
    echo '"Nothing to be done for" was present in output'
else
    echo '"Nothing to be done for" was NOT present in output'
fi
```

We capture the output from `make`, then grep (options quiet and fixed
string) for the string you're seeking. If found, the exit status of
`grep` is 0; if not found, 1.

Afterthoughts:

`make` often generates a lot of output, so it might be best to change
the first line to:

```
mk_output=$(make (make options) | grep -qF 'Nothing to be done for')
```

That way, `mk_output` won't be so huge.

If you want to see the output from `make` as it's running, as well as
capture it, use `tee` to capture to a file instead:

```
make | tee make_output
if grep -qF 'Nothing to be done for' make_output
then etc.
```

Comment: @schily Please stop pretending you're confused when people refer to a GNU tool by its name. There's no need to call it `gwhatever` when the context is clear, and it can't be clearer in a question that's tagged [gnu-make] and says "I'm using GNU Make 4.0.". Whatever personal vendetta you have going on is your business, but you're confusing people for no reason